# I want to know the opening date and time of any chat application through the programming in android

Tags: android

I am doing coding in android for to know the date and time of chats app when they open last time.please help.

Comment: Please provide what all strategies that you've tried/attempted.

Comment: i am new in android. but till now i did coding for to get date and time for current app. want to get date and time for other apps.

Comment: `please help.` sure, but you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this in my chat app with firebase so you can try this :-

create a static method which method is used in across the app :-

```
public static void userStatus(String status) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(onlineStatusTable).child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        try {
            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("status", status);
            reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and call this method in your activity onStart method:-

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        userStatus(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        super.onStart();
    }
```

and when you retrieve the milliseconds from server then converts like this :-

```
public static String getMyPrettyDate(long neededTimeMilis) {
        Calendar nowTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar neededTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        neededTime.setTimeInMillis(neededTimeMilis);

        if ((neededTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) == nowTime.get(Calendar.YEAR))) {

            if ((neededTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) == nowTime.get(Calendar.MONTH))) {

                if (neededTime.get(Calendar.DATE) - nowTime.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) {
                    //here return like "Tomorrow at 12:00 AM/PM"
                    return "Tomorrow at " + DateFormat.format("hh:mm aaa", neededTime);

                } else if (nowTime.get(Calendar.DATE) == neededTime.get(Calendar.DATE)) {
                    //here return like "Today at 12:00 AM/PM"
                    return "Today at " + DateFormat.format("hh:mm aaa", neededTime);

                } else if (nowTime.get(Calendar.DATE) - neededTime.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) {
                    //here return like "Yesterday at 12:00 AM/PM"
                    return "Yesterday at " + DateFormat.format("hh:mm aaa", neededTime);

                } else {
                    //here return like "May 31, 12:00 AM/PM"
                    return DateFormat.format("MMMM d, hh:mm aaa", neededTime).toString();
                }

            } else {
                //here return like "May 31, 12:00 AM/PM"
                return DateFormat.format("MMMM d, hh:mm aaa", neededTime).toString();
            }

        } else {
            //here return like "May 31 2010, 12:00 AM/PM" - it's a different year we need to show it
            return DateFormat.format("MMMM dd yyyy, hh:mm aaa", neededTime).toString();
        }
    }
```

and set you textView like this :-

```
status.setText(getMyPrettyDate(Long.parseLong(dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString())));
```

Comment: can you help me for , suppose i opened the keyboard in any app...we should get that opening date and time..

Comment: no. if i click on edittext in any app.. then we should get that date and time

Comment: you can set onClickListner on your editText and call userStatus method